Angular's httpClient.get hangs if called from Mocha unit testing with async / await pattern
I have a simple API call inside a service:
  async validate(videoId: string): Promise<YoutubeValidationResult> {
    try {
      const response = await lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.get<{ items: any[] }>(YouTubeValidationService.VIDEO_URL + videoId));
      const video = response.items?.[0];
      if (!video) return { status: 'VIDEO_NOT_FOUND' };
      return { status: 'VALID' };
    } catch (err) {
      return { status: 'INVALID' };
    }
  }

And my unit test, using await/async pattern:
    it("should return 'VALID' if video URL is valid", async () => {
      const videoId = 'NExQ06SlMt8';

      try {
        const result = await youTubeValidationService.validate(videoId);
        expect(result.status).to.be.equal('VALID');
      } catch (err) {
        assert.fail('Unexpected ' + err);
      }
    });

For some reason, the API call never returns. I can see into debug that the execution goes until that line, then stops.
However, if I change my unit test to .then() pattern, then the API call gets called and everything works:
    it("should return 'VALID' if video URL is valid", () => {
      const videoId = 'NExQ06SlMt8';

      youTubeValidationService.validate(videoId).then((result) => {
        expect(result.status).to.be.equal('VALID');
      }).catch(err => {
        assert.fail('Unexpected ' + err);
      });
    });

Everything is working fine outside unit tests also.
What is going on?

I suspect in the second case the test doesn't fail simply because you don't return the promise chain, but isn't actually succeeding either (test-driving would let you ensure it fails before implementing the behaviour). What's supposed to be handling the request in the test environment - are you using https://angular.dev/guide/http/testing?

If I call done() inside .then() it also succeeds. Yes, I'm using provideHttpClientTesting() and HttpTestingController.

Please give a [mre].

You should mock your API calls instead of actually making them, since APIs can change anytime but UT doesn't.
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it("should return 'VALID' if video URL is valid", async () => {
    spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(of({ items: ['VALID'] })); // <- changed here!
    const videoId = 'NExQ06SlMt8';
    try {
      const result = await component.validate(videoId);
      expect(result.status).toEqual('VALID');
    } catch (err) {
      // assert.fail('Unexpected ' + err);
    }
  });
});

Stackblitz Demo
